# Axios not sending data to the backend

Tags: reactjs, axios, yup

I have the following code in my backend.

```
import { Request, Response } from "express";
import * as yup from "yup";
import ElectionContract, { web3 } from "../../web3";

const schema = yup.object({
    req: yup.object({
        name: yup.string().min(3).required(),
        description: yup.string().min(10).required(),
        candidates: yup.array(
            yup.object({
                name: yup.string().min(3),
                info: yup.string().min(10),
            })
        ),
    }),
});

export default async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    try {
        await schema.validate(req);
    } catch (error: any) {
        return res.status(400).send(error.errors);
    }
};
```

Frontend code:

```
if (candidatesError === ""&& name!==""&&description!=="") {
    axios
        .post("/polls/start",{name,description, candidates})
        .then((_) => {
            window.location.reload();
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            let error = err.message;
            if (err?.response?.data) error = err.response.data;
            setError(error);
            setLoading(false);
        });
    }
}}
```

I have make sure that name and description must not be empty. But when I make the call, schema validation says that `req.name` is a required field in backend.

How can I solve the error? I am learning React.js and Node.js.

Answer (score 0):

The yup.object() method expects an object with keys that match the field names defined in the schema. In your case, the schema defines a field called req, which is an object that contains the fields name, description, and candidates. Therefore, you should pass the request body as an object with a req property that contains those fields, like this:

```js
await schema.validate({ req: req.body });
```

This will ensure that the request body is validated against the schema correctly.

Also, it's worth noting that the frontend code you provided seems to have a logical error in the if statement condition. The condition currently checks if candidatesError is empty OR if name and description are not empty. This means that if candidatesError is not empty but name and description are empty, the axios.post() call will still be made, which may result in a validation error on the server side. It's recommended to update the condition to check if candidatesError is empty AND if name and description are not empty, like this:

```js
if (candidatesError === "" && name !== "" && description !== "") {
  // make axios.post() call
}
```